# Command Prompt does not execute .py file correctly?

Tags: python, cmd, command, command-prompt, prompt

I use Adobe products (such as Premiere Pro/Photoshop) a lot and wanted to have Discord Rich Presence implementation.
I found a very useful python script for this: https://github.com/smokes/adobe-rpc

If I manually execute it (opens command prompt) it works perfectly fine, it detects my Discord and Premiere Pro/Photoshop and displays it correctly in Discord.

However I wanted to run this script when I launch Premiere Pro/Photoshop so I used a batch file for this:

```
@echo off

start "Premiere Pro" "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2019\Adobe Premiere Pro.exe"
ping -n 20 localhost

python "E:\Software\Python\Adobe Discord Rich Presence\adobe-rpc-master\rpc.py"
```

It opens the script as it should but when it actually launches the script, the script can not find Discord or the Adobe software.
It just states "Run Adobe/Discord App".

I have tested the script by opening a fresh Command Prompt and dragging the script in: same result as stated above. It can not find Discord or the Adobe software.

This is very strange to me as I can perfectly run it if I open it manually but not if I run it in the Command Prompt?

Furthermore, Python does not give an actual error message, just the "error message" that is built inside the script.

When I launch it manually, it opens in the Command Prompt so I am very confused as to why this happens.

Can anyone explain this/help me?
I am very new to the Command Prompt and Python.

Comment: Why not try to download the exe from releases (https://github.com/smokes/adobe-rpc/releases) and start that from your script?

Comment: The exe file is only for Photoshop for some reason. You got me thinking tho, so I turned the .py file into an exe file using  [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZSZHmWSOeM) However, this did not work either... It had the same "Run Adobe/Discord" (cannot find the software) problem. Also I noticed that the title of the command prompt while running the original .py file leads to C:\Windows\py.exe WHICH IS AN EXE FILE. But when I run that one, it doesn't work either. I am very confused right now...

Answer (score 0):

Warning! This is comment and maybe answer both!

First of all: do you have `Python 3.4>=` added in `PATH`? If not add.

Second: Do you followed instructions in `README.md`? If not follow!

Third: Which `Adoble` application do you use and is it available in `adobe-rpc`'s repository? If not then wait for next update of `adobe-rpc`.

Fourth: Try to open script in it's directory and this is how:

1. Go to script's folder
2. Hold `SHIFT` and click `RMB`, also called `Right Button Mouse`. In menu `Open Command Prompt here` or `Open Powershell here` must be displayed.
3. If `Open Command Prompt here` is displayed instead of `Open Powershell here`, click it.
4. Now do: `python scriptname.py` ~ I don't know that script usage and if it requires arguments, just do `python scriptname.py arguments`.
5. If `Open Powershell here` is displayed instead of `Open Command Prompt here`. Go back, but first copy directory.
6. Then press `WIN`+`R` and in `Run` input type `cmd`.
7. In `Command Prompt`(`CMD`) type `cd` and paste your directory, then hit `Enter`.
8. Now do same as in `4.` line.

Maybe this would help.
Otherwise I don't know.